# React - Component not updating

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm creating a simple **todo app** using **react**. I have **components** for **title**, adding tasks and listing tasks. My title component accepts a prop to display the number of items in the tasks array. When I add items the number in the title does not get updated. I have attached my code below

```
//App.js
export default class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {list:[]}
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this)
  }

  addItem(val) {
    this.state.list.push(val);
    this.setState = {list:this.state.list};
    console.log(this.state.list);
    console.log(this.state.list.length)
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <Title itemCount={this.state.list.length}></Title>
      <Add addItem={this.addItem}></Add>
      <Items items={this.state.list}></Items>
    </div>
  );
  }
  
}

//Title.js
const Title = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Todo - {props.itemCount} items</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

What can I do to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mutate state in React - your `push` mutates the `list`. On reconciliation, since React sees that the old state is the same as the new state (the array in state is the same), re-rendering doesn't occur.

Instead, use:

```
addItem(val) {
  this.setState({
    list: [...this.state.list, val]
  })
}
```

Comment: This may work (it probably mostly will), but it's better to use a function argument to `setState` than to directly reference `this.state` in an object.

Comment: If `addItem` may be called twice synchronously before re-render occurs, yeah, you'll want to use the callback form - but that's somewhat unusual in my experience

Answer (score 1):

It's not the right way to update state.

```
addItem(val) {
    let updated = [...this.state.list, val];
    this.setState({ list: updated })
  }
```

**Why Not To Modify React State Directly**

Mutating state directly can lead to odd bugs, and components that are hard to optimize.